# Rename XmlElement attribute name

Tags: c#, .net, xml-deserialization

so I need to deserialize some XML files, **I'm trying to rename a property attribute in the child classes.**

The structure is very simples but I'm struggling on this. I already tried several examples but none works, hope someone can help me with this.

I have several XML files but the structure for all of them is the same:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ClassNameHeader Version="0">
  <ElementName attributes... />
  <ElementName attributes... />
  ...
</ClassNameHeader>
```

Basically I have a root "ClassNameHeader" where ClassName is set for each child of RefXMLRoot, this acts as a base class so I can have like, i.e: Foo.xml (FooRefXML -> FooHeader, Bar.xml (BarRefXML -> BarHeader) and so on. Examples:

**Foo.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<FooHeader Version="0">
  <Foo attributes... />
  <Foo attributes... />
  ...
</FooHeader>
```

**Bar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<BarHeader Version="0">
  <Bar attributes... />
  <Bar attributes... />
  ...
</BarHeader>
```

As you can see **each XML has a different element name, that's why I need to change the XmlElement attribute name to match each file**, like `[XmlElements("Foo")]` for Foo.xml or `[XmlElements("Bar")]` for Bar.xml and so on.

**Base class structure:**

```
public abstract class RefXMLRoot<RefElementType>
{
    [XmlAttribute("Version")]
    public Int32 Version{ get; set; }

    [XmlElement]
    public List<RefElementType> Elements { get; set; }

    public RefXMLRoot()
    { }
}
```

**Child class structure:**

```
[XmlRoot("FooHeader", IsNullable = false)]
[XmlElementsOverride(ElementName = "Foos")] // This is the attribute that I'm using to store the Elements attribute name.
public class FooRef : RefXMLRoot<FooElement>
{
    // Here is the tricky part
    // I want to rename this Elements attribute name that is from base class
    // using the ElementName passed to XmlElementsOverride
    // So here would be like:
    // [XmlElement("Foos")]
    // public List<FooElement> Elements { get; set; }

    public FooRef()
    { }
}
```

As I commented on code, I want to change the `Elements` `XmlElement` for each class, depending on what I pass to XmlElementsOverride.

I'm trying to do this with `XmlAttributeOverrides` when deserializing:

```
...
XmlReaderSettings xmlReaderSettings = new XmlReaderSettings();
xmlReaderSettings.IgnoreWhitespace = true;
xmlReaderSettings.IgnoreComments = true;

using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(FilePath))
{
    Type rootType = typeof(RefRootType);
    XmlElementsOverrideAttribute elementsAttribute = rootType.GetCustomAttribute<XmlElementsOverrideAttribute>(true);
    if (elementsAttribute != null)
    {
        // ElementName passed to XmlElementsOverride on Root class.
        string elementsName = elementsAttribute.ElementName;

        XmlAttributeOverrides xmlAttributeOverrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
        xmlAttributeOverrides.Add(typeof(RefRootType), "Elements", new XmlAttributes
        {
            XmlArray = new XmlArrayAttribute(elementsName),
            XmlArrayItems = {
                new XmlArrayItemAttribute(typeof(RefElementType))
            }
        });

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(RefRootType), xmlAttributeOverrides);
        Root = (RefRootType)serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
    }
}
...
```

`RefRootType` and `RefElementType` are both generic types passed to this class. `RefRootType` is `RefXMLRoot` child class and `RefElementType` is a `RefXMLElement` child class.

In resume, **I just want to rename the Elements attribute name when deserializing my XMLs.**

So, that's it, I'm out of options and I don't know if what I want to do is possible, but I think it is, I'm just missing something.

Any help will be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you explain what happens when you try to do what you already have done? E.g. a stack trace in case of a exception.

Comment: @osfresia The XML file just can't be deserialized correctly, Version property is deserialized but Elements isn't , Count keeps 0. I think that is because the XmlElement is not correct even using XmlAttributeOverrides to change it to the correct name. No exception occurs.

Answer (score 1):

**I got it, finally!**

The reason why the `Elements` property wasn't changing it's `XmlElement` attribute name is because I needed to **add the override to the base** class not the child, like I was doing.

So the solution is:

```
...
XmlAttributeOverrides xmlAttributeOverrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
XmlAttributes xmlAttributes = new XmlAttributes();                  
xmlAttributes.XmlElements.Add(new XmlElementAttribute(elementsName, typeof(RefElementType)));
                 
xmlAttributeOverrides.Add(typeof(RefXMLRoot<RefElementType>), "Elements", xmlAttributes);

XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(RefRootType), xmlAttributeOverrides);
Root = (RefRootType)serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
...
```

The **main change is** at `xmlAttributeOverrides.Add(typeof(RefXMLRoot<RefElementType>)...` here I have to refer to my **base class** `RefXMLRoot`, where `Elements` property is, not the child `RefRootType`

**Another important change** was in `xmlAttributes`

```
xmlAttributes.XmlElements.Add(new XmlElementAttribute(elementsName, typeof(RefElementType)))
```

Changed `typeof(List<RefElementType>)` to `typeof(RefElementType)` and instead of `xmlAttributes.XmlArray` I used `xmlAttributes.XmlElements`, that makes sense since `Elements` property is a `XmlElement`.

I though that the `Type` passed to `typeof` was the same as my `Elements` (`List<RefElementType>`) but if you have a `List<Type>` and you want to change this `List<>` name you just need to pass the `Type` into the `typeof`.

So, that's it, if have any questions I'll be happy to answer.